# No entiendo que hace y como lo hace la siguiente funcion

Tags: c++

Necesito saber que hace cada parte de este codigo

```
int Funcion (int A [] , int valor , int n , int i );
{
    if ( i == n + 1);
        return -1;
    else if ( A [ i ]== valor );
        return i ;
    else
        return Funcion (A , valor ,n , i + 1);
    return -1;
}
```

Que hace cada Funcion y cada variable por individual

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Hace unos cuantos `if` y devuelve cosas.

Comment: Qué entendiste tú? Qué duda quisieras resolver?

Comment: El muchacho no entiende los fundamentos probablemente, es por eso que pregunta de esa forma no porque quiera que le hagan la tarea quizá lol

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster porfaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: @RicardoCuaresma puede ser, pero en ese caso, para poder explicarle que pasa, y que la respuesta no se transforme en medio libro de C, estaria bueno saber que entendio hasta ahora y que sabe, para no tener que explicarle los fundamentos del lenguaje desde cero...

Comment: El ejercicio es sobre una funcion recursiva. Que entendes que hace, como lo hace, y como van tomando los valores a medida que se va ejecutando?

Comment: Entiendo que es una funcion, entiendo los valores pero no entiendo cuando llega eso de "Return -1" y  que es el "Return -1" y tampoco logro entender la condicion para llegar a ello.

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo programacion y eso lo estaba leyendo asi como esrta en una pagina, pero realmente esa pagina no explica eso, te preguntan que logras entender pero luego cambian de eso a funciones. Me quede con la duda y quise preguntar.

Comment: @Ferbi Hombre, si en el sitio no explican bien, y viendo que no se recalcan cosas importantes, te recomendaria el estudiar progra en otro lado. Asi te ahorras dolores de cabeza

Comment: @Ferbi sabes lo que es una funcion recursiva? porque esto que esta aca, es una forma muy compleja de buscar un valor en un array, usando una funcion recursiva...

Comment: @Pablochaches si, eso hare la verdad por que entendi un poco de lo que va pero algunas cosas como que no las terminan de explicar o se dan por entendido ellos que tu ya tiene un grado de programacion superior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mira, esa funcion te deja una leccion para futuro. Hay que darle buenos nombres a las cosas. Si le cambiamos los nombres a las variables, y ponemos comentarios, la funcion habla por si sola.

Primero, quitemos los errores de sintaxis, tienes unos `;` de mas en tu codigo

```cpp
int Funcion (int A [] , int valor , int n , int i )
{
    if ( i == n + 1)
        return -1;
    else if ( A [ i ]== valor )
        return i ;
    else
        return Funcion (A , valor ,n , i + 1);
    return -1;
}
```

Y ahora demole mejores nombres, y unos comentarios diciendo que es lo que hace:

```cpp
int buscarValorEnArray(int array[] , int valor , int tamanoDelArray , int posicionActual)
{
    // Si nos pasamos del tamaño del array, regresamos -1 indicando que el valor no esta
    // en el array
    if ( posicionActual == tamanoDelArray + 1)
        return -1;

    // Si encontramos el el valor en la posicion en la que vamos, regresamos la posicion
    else if ( array[posicionActual]== valor )
        return posicionActual;
        
    // Y si no esta el valor, pues seguimos a la siguiente posicion
    else
        return buscarValorEnArray(array , valor ,tamanoDelArray , posicionActual + 1);
        
    // Este en realidad no sirve, pero si por algun motivo llegamos aqui, regrasamos
    // que el valor no esta en el array
    return -1;
}
```

**Nota:** Supongo que el -1 significa que no esta en el array. No le encuentro otro sentido.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Ferbi la formade decir gracias aca es aceptando la respuesta que te sirvio...

Comment: Claro, entiendo que el -1 es una posición inválida... lanzar una excepción sería más correcto.

Comment: @Intento_de_programador Amigo, es una pregunta para novatos, no le metas mas complicaciones